# Cannot generate PKCS#12 keystore to use in Chrome

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I'm trying to generate PKCS#12 keystore with Java and BouncyCastle:

```
// yesterday
Date validityBeginDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
// in 2 years
Date validityEndDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 2 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

// GENERATE THE PUBLIC/PRIVATE RSA KEY PAIR
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());

KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

// GENERATE THE X509 CERTIFICATE
X509V1CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V1CertificateGenerator();
X500Principal dnName = new X500Principal("CN=" + username);

certGen.setSerialNumber(serial);
certGen.setSubjectDN(dnName);
certGen.setIssuerDN(dnName); // use the same
certGen.setNotBefore(validityBeginDate);
certGen.setNotAfter(validityEndDate);
certGen.setPublicKey(keyPair.getPublic());
certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");

X509Certificate cert = certGen.generate(keyPair.getPrivate(), "BC");

KeyStore clientKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");

clientKeystore.load(null, null);

clientKeystore.setKeyEntry("mkey", keyPair.getPrivate(), null, new X509Certificate[] { cert });

clientKeystore.store(new FileOutputStream("admin.pkcs"), "pass".toCharArray());
```

The keystore is generated just fine, but when I'm trying to load it to Chrome, it shows `Unknown error`. I've tried to load it with `pk12util` and got more detailed error message:

```
pk12util: PKCS12 decode import bags failed: SEC_ERROR_PKCS12_UNABLE_TO_IMPORT_KEY: Unable to import.  Error attempting to import private key.
```

How can I generate valid PKCS#12 keystore to use it with browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me (Win7, Jdk7,bcprov-jdk16 1.46). I can generate a pkcs12 file and import it. The differences with your code are probably in the versions of OS/JRE/BC, the line : Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()) and some compilation fixes;

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalStateException, SignatureException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    // yesterday
    Date validityBeginDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    // in 2 years
    Date validityEndDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 2 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    // GENERATE THE PUBLIC/PRIVATE RSA KEY PAIR
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());

    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

    // GENERATE THE X509 CERTIFICATE
    X509V1CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V1CertificateGenerator();
    X500Principal dnName = new X500Principal("CN=" + "username");

    certGen.setSerialNumber(new BigInteger("100"));
    certGen.setSubjectDN(dnName);
    certGen.setIssuerDN(dnName); // use the same
    certGen.setNotBefore(validityBeginDate);
    certGen.setNotAfter(validityEndDate);
    certGen.setPublicKey(keyPair.getPublic());
    certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");

    X509Certificate cert = certGen.generate(keyPair.getPrivate(), "BC");

    KeyStore clientKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");

    clientKeystore.load(null, null);

    clientKeystore.setKeyEntry("mkey", keyPair.getPrivate(), null, new X509Certificate[] { cert });

    clientKeystore.store(new FileOutputStream("admin.pkcs"), "pass".toCharArray());
}
```

Comment: I've found the error source of my problem - password of `KeyEntry` and of keystore must be the same